# Why does redirected standard output appear after process has finished?

Tags: c#, python, process

I am working with Visual Studio 2015 and .NET framework 4.7.2. I have set up a simple test program that executes an external program in C#. The program is a Python script that simply prints some string to stdout every 0.5 seconds. I want to read the stdout of this sub process in my C# application.

The program basically works, but I get the output of the Python script only shortly before the sub process exits. What do I need to change in order to get a more responsive behavior, i.e. getting the output every 0.5 second as soon as the Python script writes it to stdout?

Here's my C# code:

```
public class Program {

    private Process process;

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        new Program().init();
    }

    private void init() {
        startPythonProcess();
        process.WaitForExit();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void startPythonProcess() {
        if(process==null) {
            try {

                Console.WriteLine("Starting Python process ...");

                string filepath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).Substring(6);
                process = new Process();

                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.WorkingDirectory = filepath;
                startInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
                //startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}", Path.Combine(filepath, "test.py"));

                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceivedEventHandler;
                process.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorDataReceivedEventHandler;

                process.Start();

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            } catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not start Python process: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OutputDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args) {
        Console.WriteLine("[PYTHON] INFO: {0}", args.Data);
    }

    public void ErrorDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args) {
        Console.WriteLine("[PYTHON] ERROR: {0}", args.Data);
    }

}
```

Here's my Python script:

```
import time
import sys
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0
    while True:
        print('PYTHON: {}'.format(count))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        count+=1
        if count>=25:
            break
```

UPDATE: I uploaded the mini project [here](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13516028/MiscTests.zip.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function takes a *flush* argument which controls whether buffered output is flushed.

The default value of *flush* is `False`, meaning flushing is controlled by whatever file `print` is writing to (for example, `sys.stdout`).

Set *flush* to True to force immediate printing.

```
print('PYTHON: {}'.format(count), flush=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, the behaviour is still the same. I get the stdout in my C# application only shortly before the process exits (it then prints the whole bunch of messages at once). I uploaded the project (cp. to bottom line at original post for the link).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am using Python 2.7.15. I guess that's why `flush=True` didn't work and I just used `True`. Having a look on the 2.7.15 API definition for `print()` I can't spot a flush parameter. Is there a flush feature in 2.7.15 for `print` at all?

Comment: Checked now with Python 3.7.2 and it's working fine. Thank you!

Comment: In Python2 you'd need to do `from __future__ import print_function` - the old `print` statement doesn't have the flush capability (though you could still flush `sys.stdout` directly).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!